# getting error in calling stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, stored-procedures

if i run this model program without stored procedure calling means working fine.But if i calling stored procedure means throwing error.please help me i think the way of representing table name is wrong while calling stored procedure.

**MODEL**

```
 <?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

     class Members_model extends CI_Model 
     {       
         function select_members() 
         {           
             $query = $this->db->get('users'); //Table Name
             $query = $this->db->query("CALL get_members()");// calling stored procedure
             return $query->result_array();         
         }      
     }
?>
```

**NOTE: Thrown Error**
A Database Error Occurred

```
Error Number: 2014

Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

UPDATE `users` SET `username` = 'ThottiJaya', `password` = '28bf' WHERE `id` = 127

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

Comment: What is the error thrown?

Comment: Thrown Error:  A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 2014

Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

UPDATE `users` SET `username` = 'ThottiJaya', `password` = '28bf' WHERE `id` = 127

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Answer (score 1):

As per MySQL:

> C.5.2.14. Commands out of sync
> If you get Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now in your client code, you are > calling client functions in the wrong order.
>
> This can happen, for example, if you are using mysql_use_result() and try to execute a new query before you have called mysql_free_result(). It can also happen if you try to execute two queries that return data without calling mysql_use_result() or mysql_store_result() in between.

I am assuming that, before making a call to `update`, you have some result set opened up and not used yet. And hence is the error. If you have nothing to do with the result, then you should be calling `mysql_free_result()` and then go for `update` call.

***Refer To***: [***MySQL: Commands out of sync***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/commands-out-of-sync.html)

***Refer To similar posts***:
[*SO: Why I am getting the Error “Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now”*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339628/why-i-am-getting-the-error-commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now)

---

There is also a case where you need to change your mysql driver to `mysqli`.

***Refer to similar post***:
[*SO: MySQL Error - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16029729/mysql-error-commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change database driver in your config from:

> $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';

to

> $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';