# Adding trigger to MySQL by PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, triggers

I use PhpMyAdmin to run the following SQL statement.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `insert_channel_test2` AFTER DELETE ON `channel_test2` FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO `tv`.`LOG_test2` (`table_name`, `table_action`) VALUES('channel_test2', 'delete');
```

It works successful, but when I use the PHP webpage to query above code, it occurs Fatal error.

```
$query = "CREATE TRIGGER `insert_channel_test2` AFTER DELETE ON `channel_test2` FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO `tv`.`LOG_test2` (`table_name`, `table_action`) VALUES('channel_test2', 'delete');"
$this->link = new mysqli( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME );
$full_query = $this->link->multi_query( $query );
```

And the error messages is following.

```
 Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

Does everyone knows what the problem is?
Thanks!

Comment: Permission error perhaps, try actually printing the error message..

Comment: What is the actual error from mysqli that you can get with [`mysqli_error`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)? What you posted is your custom error message, that shows the time and the query which is nine, but doesn't contain the real error message from MySQL.

Comment: sorry, the following error message is produced by `mysqli_error`.     **Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per MySQL:

> C.5.2.14. Commands out of sync
> If you get Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now in your client code,
> you are calling client functions in the wrong order.
>
> This can happen, for example, if you are using `mysql_use_result()` and try to execute a new query before you have called `mysql_free_result()`. It can also happen if you try to execute two queries that return data without calling `mysql_use_result()` or `mysql_store_result()` in between.

***Refer to***:

- [***MySQL: Commands out of sync***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/commands-out-of-sync.html)
- One of my answers to a similar query on SO: [***getting error in
  calling stored procedure***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20346454/767881)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Everybody.
I modified my code to following, and fix the problem.

```
public function multi_query( $query )
{
    $query = $this->link->multi_query( $query );
    $this->clear_next();
    if(  mysqli_error( $this->link ) )
    {
        $this->log_db_errors( mysqli_error( $this->link ), $query, 'Fatal' );
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
    mysqli_free_result( $query );
} 

public function clear_next()
{
    while($this->link->more_results())
    {
        $this->link->next_result();
        if($res = $this->link->store_result())
        {
            $res->free(); 
        }
    }
}
```